# ng serve throws node_modules appears empty error

Tags: angular

I just started learning Angular 4, and as part of learning process i did the following:

Install `Node.js (version 8)`.

Ran this command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

created a new project through CLI: `ng new my-first-app`

As soon as i ran this command: `ng serve`, i got an error `node_module` appear empty, you may need to run 'npm install'. Once i run npm install, it installed a few libraries and now `ng serve` builds and runs the project. i am trying to understand why did i need to `npm install` and what did it install? shouldn't all the prerequisites have been installed with this command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. With this command(npm install -g @angular/cli) you install only one package angular/cli globally so you can use from terminal anywhere in your system to scaffold your project. But the project depends on a lot of local packages to install them you need to

1. navigate to the project

> cd my-first-app

2. Install node modules

> npm install or npm i

Comment: so does that mean, everytime i create a new project, i need to run this command and the libraries installed are only specific to this project?

Comment: yes You are right. You will find the list of libraries in package.json file

Comment: npm install command will not work till we navigate to the newly created application folder. In this scenario its : 
cd my-first-app

and then run

npm install

Answer (score 9):

When you create an angular app from terminal

> ng new my-first-app

you usually be one folder level up in the terminal. Navigate to your project path

> cd my-first-app

and run

> npm install

it should get resolved.

Comment: i was facing same error while running "ng serve" outside project root folder. running it from root folder worked with out the mentioned error. +1

Comment: you saved me today

Answer (score -2):

I have ran `npm install` but I am still getting the same `node_modules` appears empty, you may need to run `npm install` which I have done many times